# How to filter out X largest values of struct

Tags: swift, xcode, filter, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct stats: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID().uuidString
  var category: String
  var amount: Int
  var name: String
  var animate: Bool = false
}

static var array:[stats] = []
```

An array containing this struct gets very quickly populated and I want to filter out the X largest arrays inside the struct depending on the value of the amount. So the top X amount-values inside the struct. Do anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `sort` the array and use `prefix` to take the first X?

Comment: by "gets very quickly populated" do you mean that this is a continuously changing set of data and at any point in time you want the top X values; or is it static?

Comment: @flanker it's static, the filtering will happen when no change to the data is happening

Comment: I think we might be having a language problem here. You said " I want to filter out the X largest arrays inside the struct".  Your struct does not contain any arrays. You have an array of structs. I gather you want to select the x structs from your array of structs based on the amount field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the first 3 `stats` structs from an array of `stats` structs, you could use code like this:

```
struct stats: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var category: String
    var amount: Int
    var name: String
    var animate: Bool = false
}

var array:[stats] = [
    stats(category: "noises", amount: 12, name: "snork"),
    stats(category: "noises", amount: 3, name: "giggle"),
    stats(category: "noises", amount: 1, name: "whimper"),
    stats(category: "colors", amount: 7, name: "blue"),
    stats(category: "colors", amount: 2, name: "red"),
    stats(category: "pencils", amount: 6, name: "Number Two"),
    stats(category: "pencils", amount: 4, name: "Dixon Ticonderoga"),
]

let sorted = array.sorted { (lhv, rhv) -> Bool in
    return lhv.amount < rhv.amount
}

let firstThree = sorted.suffix(3)
firstThree.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

That prints:

```
stats(id: "80B9522E-79A2-4332-8C5B-2B6B7EAD1F30", category: "pencils", amount: 6, name: "Number Two", animate: false)
stats(id: "0C90AD31-61B3-4174-B5FA-984CE8AD0474", category: "colors", amount: 7, name: "blue", animate: false)
stats(id: "0A8D6736-8494-4469-973E-2DBF01F569B3", category: "noises", amount: 12, name: "snork", animate: false)
```

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/MinMax.md

Comment: Could provide inconsistent results if there are multiple structs in the array with the same value (which is an issue with the question, not the answer!) as the output would depend on the order of the input.

Comment: As flanker pointed out, the results would be undetermined if you have multiple items in your array that have the same amount value. It would depend on the sort algorithm. Also note that a very good sort algorithm tends to have `O(n•log n)` time performance. You could likely get `O(n)` time performance for a small number of items by doing single  pass through the array collecting the items with the n largest amount values, but it would require more code. Unless you're sorting thousands of items it wouldn't make that much difference.